# Usage of SquareConnect::CustomersApi.search_customers method

Tags: ruby, square-connect

I want to search customers by name SquareConnect::CustomersApi.search_customers,but the response returned all customer profiles.

The codes below are almost the same as codes of "https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2/2018-09-18#endpoint-searchcustomers".

```
access_token=Constants::ACCESS_TOKEN
SquareConnect.configure do |config|
  config.access_token = access_token
end
api = SquareConnect::CustomersApi.new
api.search_customers({
  query: {
    filter: {
      family_name: {
        values: ["test"],
        rule: SquareConnect::CustomerInclusionExclusion::INCLUDE
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to API Documents,DataTypes:CustomerFilter,
fields to be able to filter for SquareConnect::CustomersApi.search_customers are below, Now.

- creation_source
- created_at
- updated_at

I think,this method's function is insufficient....